# Animation 2D all frames moves at once

Tags: keyframes, 2d

I'm trying to make a 2d animation for my school project. When I was making and arranging the frame, it was smooth process first. But after a while, when I tried to move one keyframe it moved every other one on the same layer at once, it wasn't like this before. Example:
[image]

I tried to move only one of the frame.

[image]
but it moved all at once.

Can anybody help?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already found out the answer. The proportional editing needs to be turned off.

Comment: I am really surprised! I didn't know that proportional editing affects keyframes too.

Comment: Sometimes it's a bit annoying. But its good if you want to move all of the keyframes at once.

Comment: It is also done by Shift+Click, i think so